# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MathField'

Tags: django, attributes

After I makemigrations, I am getting this error when I try to migrate. mathfield is installed in INSTALLED_APPS.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import mathfield

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    latex = mathfield.MathField(default=timezone.now)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

django-mathfield is installed in my virtualenv
[django-mathfield usage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mathfield)
The error happens with the default or if I allow the one-off default during makemigrations.

Answer (score 0):

This package is for Django 1.7. If you are using a newer version of Django, the package may have failing imports. If this is the case, you can revert to an earlier version of Django or you can modify the django-mathfield package to match your version of Django.

Edit:
I looked at the library code, and it seems the imports in `__init__.py` are causing issues. I was able to get it to work by removing the top imports from `mathfield/__init__.py`:

```
# from mathfield.api import *
# from mathfield.models import *
# from mathfield.widgets import *
```

And changing your code as follows:

```
from mathfield.models import MathField

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    latex = MathField(default=timezone.now)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
    blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: I was in Django 1.8 but after downgrading, I still get the same import error. I'll try something else and see if it works. I'm using Python 2.7 and Django 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ pip install django-mathfield
```

install math field first then do it

```
import mathfield
```